# Javafx picture to low poly art converter

Tags: image-processing, javafx

I'm trying to make a program with javafx that will convert a picture like this:
[image: left: normal picture, right : low poly picture]

In this picture, the background isn't really the way I'd like it, but the avocado in the middle is a great example of what I want to achieve. What I have now is two filters that will find edges in the picture based on brightness like so:

```
public void processImage() {
    ww = (int) Math.ceil(image.getWidth());
    hh = (int) Math.ceil(image.getHeight());
    pixelAmount = (long) ww * (long) hh;
    pxDA = new pxInfo[ww][hh];
    PixelReader pr = image.getPixelReader();
    if(pr != null) {
        System.out.println("pixel reader found");
        WritableImage i = new WritableImage(ww, hh);
        for(int x = 0; x < ww; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < hh; y++) {
                Color c = pr.getColor(x, y);
                double a = c.getOpacity();
                double r = c.getRed();
                double g = c.getBlue();
                double b = c.getBlue();

                double[][] gray = new double[3][3];
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        if(!((j == 0 && x == 0) || (k == 0 && y == 0) || (j 
== 2 && x == ww - 1) || (k == 2 && y == hh - 1))) {
                            Color cl = pr.getColor(x - 1 + j, y - 1 + k);
                            gray[j][k] = 0.299 * cl.getRed() +  0.587 * 
cl.getGreen() + 0.114 * cl.getBlue();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // apply filter
                double gray1 = 0, gray2 = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                        gray1 += gray[j][k] * filter1[j][k];
                        gray2 += gray[j][k] * filter2[j][k];
                    }
                }
                double magnitude = clamp(0.0, 1.0 - Math.sqrt(gray1 * gray1 + 
gray2 * gray2), 1.0);
                Color color = new Color(magnitude, magnitude, magnitude, 1);
                i.getPixelWriter().setColor(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        stackPane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(i));
    }
}
```

And this part of the code works quite well, these are some results:

before filter:
[image: before applying filters]
after filter:
[image: after applying filters]
But the problem is that I don't know where to go from here. I'm looking for all sorts of algorithms on the internet, but I can't really find anything with clear explanation, so I thought I'd ask here. So if you know some algorithm / filter that I can apply to improve this, I'd like to hear.

Then there's also the part where I actually need to create the triangels / polygons. Say I have the filters all applied etc, what do I do then? Like how do I distinguish a shape from just a grayscale picture? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Lenardjee

Comment: Have you ever found a solution / library to creating a low poly image? AFAIK there is an algorithm called delaunay triangulation but I'm not 100% sure if it can be used on your image data.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it yet, but I will look into the delaunay triangulation and see what I can do with it, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with JavaFX in particular, but I've attempted a very similar problem using **Python** and **OpenCV**:

https://github.com/tasercake/lowpolypy

Here's how I went about it.

---

## General Flow:

1. Pre-process image (Bilateral / Gaussian blur to remove noise, etc.)
2. Get Keypoints from image (using the methods detailed below)
3. Get Polygons from Keypoints (using Delaunay Triangulation or similar algorithm)
4. Shade Polygons (e.g. using the mean color of all pixels within the polygon)
5. Post-process (contrast, saturation adjustments, etc.)

---

## 1. Pre-processing

Pre-processing your image helps to remove a lot of unnecessary high-frequency details before you move on to Keypoint extraction.

You might achieve this using a filter such as a **Bilateral filter** or **Gaussian filter**.

You might also want to downscale your image here to speed up processing, but this isn't strictly necessary.

---

## 2. Keypoint Extraction

This is probably the most difficult part and the one that will require the most fine-tuning / experimentation.

Some methods you can try are:

#### [Canny Edge Detection](http://justin-liang.com/tutorials/canny/)

Any image manipulation / computer vision library (OpenCV, for instance) worth its salt should have this built right in.

This method gives you a boolean image where potential edges are marked 'True'. You can then select a random subset of these points and convert them to (X, Y) coordinates (or whatever format is most convenient for you).

I've found this method coupled with a tiny bit of randomization to require the least tweaking.

#### [Laplacian of Gaussian](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm)

This is another method to detect salient features in an image, but is based on the second derivative of the image's pixels (as opposed to the Canny filter, which is based on the first derivative).

This filter returns an image that you can normalize and use as a weight mask to randomly sample a set of keypoints from (perhaps there are better ways to use the filter than this, but I couldn't be bothered).

#### Random Replacement

Once you've accumulated a set of keypoints from all the other methods, you may choose to replace a small random subset of all your points with a set of randomly generated keypoints.

I've found that this helps introduce some aesthetically pleasing irregularities into the final output.

#### Jiggle Keypoints

In addition to outright replacing a small subset of keypoints, I also 'jiggled' (randomly translated) every keypoint by a very small amount. This helps introduce even more randomness, and allows you to do multiple runs of your program to get one potentially good output.

> **NOTE**: Don't forget to add the 4 corners of your image as keypoints, or you'll end up with empty/black regions around your output.

---

## 3. Connect Keypoints into Polygons

[Delaunay Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) is an algorithm that connects a set of points in a plane in such a way as to maximise the smallest angle in every triangle thus formed. (Obviously, this won't work if you don't exclusively want triangles).

---

## 4. Shade Polygons

For each polygon, you'll want to get the mean of all image pixels within the area encompassed by the polygon. OpenCV has a function (`cv2.mean(image, mask)`) that lets you do this in very few lines by passing the polygon as a binary mask.

---

Some results:

[fox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnTTk.jpg) | 
[fox_lowpoly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQOAy.jpg)

[eminem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HllPu.jpg) |
[eminem_lowpoly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0RFs.jpg)

Comment: Wow! It's been like three quarters of a year and after occasionally looking at this topic, I finally decided to give up on it, and now you come along and point me in the direction of a potential solution. Thank you so much for answering, I'll try to make some time to look into this and see what I can do with it. I'll get back to you as soon as I tried it. Thanks again!